# Is there a component built into Storybook (v6), which helps you document models?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

My components use different model types to define their props. Here is an example of the type `ColumnType`:

```
export type ColumnType<T> = { key: keyof T; label: string; rules?: Rule[]; transformers?: Transformer[] };
```

Some of the components use this model types to describe their props:

```
export type Props<T> = {
  /**
   * Description of the expected columns
   */
  columns: ColumnType<T>[];
  /**
   * Callback which is called after parsing the input
   */
  onChange?: (value: T[]) => void;
  /**
   * Callback which is called if there are validation errors
   */
  onValidation?: (errors: ValidationError<T>[]) => void;
  /**
   * Globally applied transformers
   */
  transformers?: Transformer[];
};
```

The props are nicely documented in the components story:

[image: A storybook story, showing the prop types of a component]

I've tried to use `ArgsTable` from the **docs addon** (which I'm already using), but I don't know how. I have already JSDoc comments above all my model types. Is it possible to extract them similar as Storybook does it it already with the components props?

What is the appropriate way to describe these model types with Storybook (v6)?

Comment: You mean something like https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/tree/master/addons/docs ?

Comment: Well, I'm already using the docs addon. Which block would you suggest?

Comment: Oh  yeah so you would want to directly extract the already  existing documentation ?

Comment: Yes, I will clarify my question towards that.